# Undo doesn't function in IB (Interface Builder) in Xcode 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Is anyone else having this problem? It was working a couple of days ago but now anytime I'm working in Interface Builder on a storyboard Undo simply says "Undo Change Frame Size" no matter what I do it doesn't allow undo/redo (this is VERY TEDIOUS!).

Comment: I've been having the same problem with Xcode 5. I started the project using Xcode 4.6 and after updating to Xcode 5, the Undo stopped working in Interface Builder.

Comment: You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Done, and anyone who gets this issue should file one as well so we have a better change of getting it fixed!

Comment: iOS 7 along with Xcode 5 is very, *very* buggy. You should fire a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com. My only hope is that Mavericks isn't such a hell as iOS 7 is...

Comment: Thanks for filing a Radar, Stuart. If other folks run into this as well, the more information you can provide (including steps to reliably reproduce, a sample Xcode project, etc.) the better.

Comment: Apple has responded that my ticket is a duplicate so hopefully now enough people have it in there that they're working on a fix, looking forward to 5.0.1

Comment: I have the same problem, and Xcode is constantly eating up all the CPU. somewhere, I believe, Interface Builder is constantly trying to resize something (hence the undo frame size problem) in an infinite loop, as in instruments, I've sampled Xcode and almost all the CPU is used for methods like "displayIfNeeded" or constraint/layout update methods. there is definitely an internal inconsistency in Interface Builder.

Comment: I filed a bug report. This bug has caused me lots of frustration and time..

Comment: The bug still exists on 5.0.2!!!!

Comment: I'm speculating here but is there a chance that the guys that experiencing the above are using XCode 4 & xcode 5 on same project? I got 2 versions of XCode installed and if I'll open a project with XCode 4 and then in XCode 5 there's a good chance that the "undo" will stop functioning and will stuck on "Undo Change Frame Size".

Comment: I only have Xcode 5, I think it's from older projects (i.e. ones created pre-iOS7/Xcode 5)

Comment: Any news on this with Xcode 5.1 ?

Comment: still getting this bug in xcode 7

Answer (score 2):

It also happened to me when I upgraded to Xcode 5 for some of my older projects that I've migrated. Cleaning the build folder didn't do any help. But deleting everything inside the DerivedData folder (`/Users/(your username)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`) helped me. It works much like a cache folder so deleting everything inside it is safe (everything inside there is built from your project files anyway, they just speed up things). It's probably corrupted (or incompatible) with Xcode 5. Close Xcode, delete everything inside it, and reopen Xcode, build your project. It worked for me.

*Note: If you are unsure about deleting the files in `DerivedData`, you can back it up to somewhere else before deleting it just to be on the safe side. But I can pretty much delete everything inside it with confidence.*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but in my case, i can use the undo function in the assistant editor view.

try it

I hope this help!

Comment: Are you saying that when Undo is broken for the storyboard if you switch to the assistant editor view Undo now inside the storyboard? I ask as for those who have the issue coding undo seems to always work it's just the storyboard that doesn't allow Undos.

Comment: I say that in my case if i change to the assistant editor view the Undo (inside the storyboards) work. I always change the interface in this view so i can go back if i make an error.

Comment: Next time it occurs for me I'll give this a shot and if it works then I'll mark your answer as correct (as far as a workaround anyways)!

Comment: see my answer below, it may help as it helped me to continue working with a project that I couldn't work with after installing Xcode 5..